# gradle test running the main class

Tags: gradle, build, automated-tests, testng, build.gradle

below is my problem.
i have `RunTest(main class)`, which is generating testng xml file dynamically i.e. virtual `testng.xml`.

In my `gradle.build` file i have following test which uses the static `testng.xml` file, not the virtual one:

```
test {
    useTestNG() {
        // runlist to executed. path is relative to current folder
        suites 'testng.xml'
    }
}
```

To my knowledge, when running command `gradle test` it looks for `testng.xml` file and executes the test classes defined in the `testng.xml` file.

But i want to run the main class i. e. `RunTest` when i fire command `gradle test`, so that my main method dynamically (virtual one) generates `testng.xml` and runs tests instead of static `testng.xml` file.

can anyone please help me in calling and running the main class from `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

If you main method is actually executing the tests, just define a task called `test` of type `JavaExec` with `override` set to true and it will replace the pre-existing `test` task. If your main class just generates the dynamic `testng.xml` file, just define a task `generateTestNgXML` of type `JavaExec` that that generates your `testng.xml` file and make the test task depend on your task, then configure the test task to use your generated config file.